# Set default or Global Site Collection permissions in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, web-application

In SharePoint Server on-prem, we had [WebApplication-level permission policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-permission-policies-for-a-web-application#add-users-to-or-remove-users-from-a-permission-policy-level) that could allow the administrator to setup certain users or groups to have a set of permissions on All site collections in that WebApp.  We used this for our Support team, to ensure the members of that group always had access to all sites, and likewise for global service accounts for unattended application and script execution.  The policy was automatically applied to any new site collections created in that WebApplication.  In SharePoint Online, there are no longer any WebApplications, all site collections are independent.

Is it possible to setup a similar policy (or equivalent) in Office 365 such that we can set users or groups to have the same permission across all site collections without having to manually change each site individually?  Or at least set a default such that each new Site Collection gets a default set of users and groups that could be added or removed later as necessary?

I will add that I can think of at least six different ways to schedule some custom code to periodically check and add the necessary permissions, but am looking for a configurable solution -- although I would accept if the (theoretical) settings are hidden deep in the API and have to be initially set via code.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule a poweshell script to loop through all sites collection and add site collection admins to any site currenlty missing them. A script for that is [here](https://modery.net/setting-administrators-on-all-sharepoint-online-site-collections/).

While not the same thing, [site scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#add-users-principals-to-sharepoint-groups) support adding specified users to the owners group (or the visitors or members group). Or, use a site script to call an azure function that specifies the site collection admin.

Comment: Yes, I am well aware of the multiple ways to code my way around this, but this client is specifically trying to avoid custom coded solutions.  Their on-prem environment has more than two dozen custom server-side solutions and hundreds of scheduled PowerShell scripts, and they feel the move to the cloud is a chance to start with a clean slate.

Comment: It isn't possible without a custom solution. There is no permission policy like on-prem.